# Add a click handler to a ref?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using a 3rd party package but need to add a small piece of interaction.

The package has a button with ref of "next". Is there anyway to add a click handler to this ref?

Answer (score 10):

This may help:

```
public mounted() {
    const next = this.$refs.next as HTMLElement;
    next.addEventListener('click', this.onNextClick, false);
}

public onNextClick() {
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: " as HTMLElement" is not needed in my case, but it is important to not refer to the refs before the element is mounted. So +1 here

Answer (score 7):

I've ran into this question seeking a solution for a similar problem. However my case was that a `ref` attribute was set on a Vue Component object. Using simple `addEventListener` on a referenced object I got an error:

> addEventListener is not a function

The solution is to call the function on referenced component's `$el` property, being an actual HTML element.

```
this.$refs.next.$el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  /* do stuff here*/
}, false);
```

From the comment's in the previous answers I see that it might also be the case for OP.

Comment: With these method, how inherit the reserved word **this** inside `function` from `listener`?

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
this.$refs.next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  /* do stuff here*/
}, false);
```

Comment: this.$refs.next is not a function

Comment: There are some questions that need to be answered here regarding the structure of your code. `this` may or may not work depending on where in the component hierarchy the `ref` attribute is attached. Without seeing the structure, the best advice you will get is to do some debugging and try to figure out under what component the ref is stored. The suggestion by @Daniel is correct if the component that you are trying to interact with is in the component that you are using the above piece of code in.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19635505)

Comment: Sorry @panthro, I'm trying with what little info you made available.

Comment: @SherylHohman. I don't know whether you're referring to my answer or to an earlier comment, but you know, your comment isn't very helpful either. You know some people try to help others even if they're questions are hard to understand, instead trying to delete anything that doesn't satisfy their sense of conformity.

Comment: @Daniel thanks, this answer helps me in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976357/manually-listen-for-mouse-event-in-vue-instance/53978596#53978596)