# Manually listen for mouse event in Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, mouseevent

I am trying to listen to a mouse event in a child component from the component, but I don't get the event being fired. It works when I listen for the event in html, but not

This works as you can see:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#mouse',
  data: {
    message: 'Hover Me!'
  },
  methods: {
    mouseover: function() {
      this.message = 'Good!'
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      this.message = 'Hover Me!'
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

body #mouse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #007db9;
}

body #mouse a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="mouse">
  <a @mouseover="mouseover" @mouseleave="mouseleave">
    {{message}}
  </a>
</div>
```

This one doesn't work because the event listening is done in code.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#mouse',
  data: {
    message: 'Hover Me!'
  },
  methods: {
    mouseover: function() {
      this.message = 'Good!'
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      this.message = 'Hover Me!'
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$on('mouseleave', this.mouseleave);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

body #mouse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #007db9;
}

body #mouse a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="mouse">
  <a @mouseover="mouseover">
    {{message}}
  </a>
</div>
```

What is the correct way of manually listening for `mouseleave` event from the component itself rather than in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second snippet the `mounted` hook function should be outside of methods, *this will not solve the problem*, and `vm.$on` function is used for custom event not for native ones like `click` and `mouseleave`, like explained [`here`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) :

if you call this :

```
 vm.$on('test', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg)
  })
```

You should have a code like the following one somewhere :

```
 vm.$emit('test', 'hi')
```

Since you're not able to use `this.$on` method, i recommend you the following solution using [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) by adding `ref` attribute to your `a` element by giving `link` or whatever you want and in the mounted hook add the following code:

```
    this.$refs.link.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      this.mouseleave()
    }, false);
```

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#mouse',
  data: {
    message: 'Hover Me!'
  },
  methods: {
    mouseover: function() {
      this.message = 'Good!'
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      this.message = 'Hover Me!'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.link.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      this.mouseleave()
    }, false);

  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

body #mouse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #007db9;
}

body #mouse a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="mouse">
  <a @mouseover="mouseover" ref="link">
    {{message}}
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: 'kin A! That documentation should be updated to make it clear what events can be used in this way. I read the link and it does not make mention of a distinction between native and non-native events.

Comment: they say for *custom events* and i have never seen vue developers use it for native events